# Hibernate interceptors

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am trying to implement method described [here](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/Home/hibernate-interceptor-for-new-entities), but can't make it work.

There are no errors during compilation, but the interceptor never fired.

DAO:

```
public class GeneralInvoicesDAO {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private Interceptor entityInterceptor;

   @Transactional
   public void update(GeneralInvoice object) {
      Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, entityInterceptor, null);

      session.saveOrUpdate(object);
   }
}
```

The intercepter class:

```
public class NewEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2914362528125673753L;

    @Override
    public Boolean isTransient(Object n) {
         Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

         try {
             logger.warn("test");
             Boolean result = Boolean.FALSE;

             BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity) n;
             if (entity.getId() <= 0L) {
                 entity.setId(null); 
                 result = Boolean.TRUE;
             }
             logger.warn(result.toString());
             return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return super.isTransient(n);
        }
     }
}
```

Config:

```
<bean id="newEntityInterceptor" class="de.crm.interceptor.NewEntityInterceptor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="newEntityInterceptor" />
    </bean>
```

What's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few observations from you code

1. You are NOT overriding any of the methods in  `EmptyInterceptor`. Check out [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) with a sample interceptor example.
2. [EmptyInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.com/jbportal/v2.2/javadoc/org/jboss/portal/core/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) provides the default implementations of an entity life cycle events which you can intercept. You need to override the method of your interest.
3. I am not sure if `transactionManager` needs any reference to the interceptor. Its purely a hibernate thing. You can do away with it. Interceptors are needed either with session or session factory (*you are using session level interceptor*).